# How to add elements to a RecyclerView permanently with a button

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am making an app in which I have a `RecyclerView` with some fixed elements that are added as soon as the application is created.

What I want to do is that when pressing a `Button`, an element is added to the `RecyclerView` and when closing it and launching it again, that new element remains.

Besides this, I am using [IndicatorView](https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView) to go scrolling and see the elements of the recyclerview. When I add some elements with the `Button` , the problem that happens to me is that the new elements are created, the `RecyclerView` increases in size but the `IndicatorView` does not increase and I cannot scroll to see the new elements added, in addition to that when restarting the application these new elements added with the button, they delete themselves.

How can I increase the size of `IndicatorView` when adding new elements to the `RecyclerView`?

How to add elements to a RecyclerView permanently using onClick on a `Button`?

## My code:

### MainActivity.kt:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
    private lateinit var pagerAdapter: PageAdapter
    private val animalList = arrayListOf<String>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        animalList.add("1")
        animalList.add("2")
        animalList.add("3")
        animalList.add("4")
        animalList.add("5")
        animalList.add("6")
        animalList.add("7")
        animalList.add("8")
        animalList.add("9")
        animalList.add("10")
        animalList.add("11")
        animalList.add("12")
        animalList.add("13")
        animalList.add("14")
        animalList.add("15")
        animalList.add("16")
        animalList.add("17")


        var size = animalList.size / 4
        if ((animalList.size % 4 ) > 0)
            size += 1

        pagerAdapter = PageAdapter(supportFragmentManager, size, animalList)

        ADDbutton.setOnClickListener {

            animalList.add("lol")
            animalList.add("añadido jaja")
            Log.i("AAA","Added: "+ animalList +" SIZE: " + animalList.size)
            pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)

        pagerAdapter = PageAdapter(supportFragmentManager, size, animalList)
        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter

    }

}
```

### ItemFragment.kt:

```
class ItemFragment : Fragment() {

  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    // Creates the view controlled by the fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, container, false)
    val recycler = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler)

    // Retrieve and display the movie data from the Bundle
    val args = arguments
    recycler.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity,2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
    recycler.adapter = ItemAdapter(args?.getStringArrayList("items")!!, this.activity!!)

    return view
  }
  companion object {

    fun newInstance(items: ArrayList<String>): ItemFragment {

      val args = Bundle()
      args.putStringArrayList("items", items)

      val fragment = ItemFragment()
      fragment.arguments = args
      return fragment
    }
  }
}
```

### PageAdapter.kt:

```
    class PageAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, private val size: Int, private val items: ArrayList<String>) :
    FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        val firstItem = ((position + 1) * 4) - 3
        val lastItem = ((position + 1) * 4)
        val itemSet = arrayListOf<String>()
        for (i in firstItem..lastItem) {
            if (i <= items.size)
                itemSet.add(items[i - 1])
        }
        return ItemFragment.newInstance(itemSet)
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return size
    }
}
```

### ItemAdapter.kt:

```
    class ItemAdapter(private val items: ArrayList<String>, private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder?.title?.text = items.get(position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }
}

class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val title: TextView = view.title_view
    val item: RelativeLayout = view.item_view

}
```

## Layouts:

### activity_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2">

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    <com.rd.PageIndicatorView
        android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_pager"
        app:piv_animationType="worm"
        app:piv_dynamicCount="true"
        app:piv_interactiveAnimation="true"
        app:piv_radius="8dp"
        app:piv_selectedColor="#000000"
        app:piv_unselectedColor="#999999"
        app:piv_viewPager="@id/view_pager"
        attrs:piv_padding="8dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="251dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ADDbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view_pager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### item.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/teal_700">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### page.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions.

1. You need to understand the [Difference between persistent and non-persistent data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476384/difference-between-persistent-and-non-persistent-data).
   Right now you create the list only in memory. You will need to also store the data somewhere. The most appropriate places would be in a database, a file or to a web backend.
2. In the `ADDbutton` `ClickListener` You are adding an item to `animalList`. But you do not set this updated list in the `PageAdapter`. The simplest approach would be to make the `items` parameter a `public var` in `PagerAdapter`'s consturctor:

```
class PageAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    private val size: Int,
    public var items: ArrayList<String>) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

}
```

The updated click listener would then look like this:

```
ADDbutton.setOnClickListener {

    animalList.add("lol")
    animalList.add("añadido jaja")
    Log.i("AAA","Added: "+ animalList +" SIZE: " + animalList.size)
    pagerAdapter.items = animalList
    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Addittionally, the size is fixed. You pass the parameter in the constructor and use it in the getCount method:

```
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return size
}
```

Instead, `getCount` should calculate the item count based on the current `items.size` value.

Comment: This is the main screen in the last page of the IndicatorView ( https://gyazo.com/a915623db6e00724a27fc01540c5d79c )  , the pages of every page of the IndicatorView are all 2x2. If I add now 5 new elements, the IndicatorView should create one more page (or dot at the bottom of the screen) and let me scroll to it and see the new elements but no new pages are created.